# How to monitor scroll position in a responsive layout?

Tags: javascript, html

When trying to track the position in a web page with a fixed-position nav bar, main content with sidebar and a footer. Like one with the following code, how to track the position with (*I don't think it's possible without, but also if* without) JS, so to be able to add/remove an `aria-current="true"` attribute to side navbar (e.g. `<li><a href="#article-title" aria-current="true"></a></li>`) when a user scroll to/away the respective part of the section? Note that sometime when there's an element that change its relative height at different viewport.

My idea was to use `IntersectionObserver`. But Instead monitoring the percentage of element is intersecting the viewport, I want to monitor if the element is reached 50-75px (probably by adding an invisible `div`) range under the nav. (So monitor if the section with id / heading with id is at the top of the viewport, but beneath nav bar). Besides, when a user navigate to a section through the link (but maybe the section is below the set range), The relevant navbar item should also have `aria-current="true"` added, until user scroll away.

**html**

```html
<header>
  <nav>...</nav>
  <div id="cover">
    <h1>...</h1>
  </div>
<header>
<div class="grid">
  <aside class="aside-1">...</aside>
  <main>
    <h2 id="article-title">...<h2>
    <section id="first-child">...</section>
    <section id="second-child">
      <p>...</p>
      <h3 id="subheading">...</h3>
      ...
    </section>
    <section id="third-child"></section>
  </main>
  <aside class="side-nav-container">
    <section class="side-nav">
      <header>...</header>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#article-title"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#first-child"></a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#second-child"></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#subheading"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#third-child"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
<footer>...</footer>
```

**css**

```css
header {
  min-height: var(--nav-height);
}
nav {
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--nav-height);
  ...
}
#cover {
  height: 300px;
  ...
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #cover {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-column: repeat(8, minimal(0, 1fr));
  ...
}
.grid .aside-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
.grid > :not(.aside-1):not(.side-nav-container) {
  grid-column: 3 / 7;
}
.grid .side-nav-container {
  grid-column: 7 / 9;
}
.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
}
.side-nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.side-nav ul li a {
    border-left: 2px solid var(--shadow);
}
.side-nav ul li a[aria-current="true"] {
    border-left: 2px solid var(--main);
}
```

Comment: Where's the JavaScript? See [ask] and how to post a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not so good at JavaScript so I wanted to leave for community to solve, but I will add my copy of JS soon.